# Drupal 7 returning empty array because of the database connection

Tags: 7, database, configuration

I am able to connect to the remote database and fetch the results when I am using `core PHP-MySQL connection`.

But Drupal 7 returns empty array when I am using the same remote database connection. The local database is working fine.

Below is my database connection in settings.php

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'test',
      'username' => 'test',
      'password' => 'test',
      'host' => '*****',
      'port' => '3316',
      'prefix' => '',
);
```

When I am accessing my site, it is just returning `Array`as output. Is it a problem with my database user permissions or should I make any changes in Drupal database settings with port?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. The problem is not in the database connection. I **cleared the cache table in the database** and it started working fine.

Earlier, I set the option **'Cache pages for anonymous users'**. May be because of this, it didn't give the output.

Thanks for your answer.